# How to access $GLOBALS['TSFE'] in TYPO3 v10

Tags: migration, typo3, changelog, typo3-10.x

The following snippet worked in the plugin for version 8 and 9.

Basically this was used to get typoscript setup from the root template.

```
 protected function getTypoScriptSetup()
    {
        

        /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Page\PageRepository $pageRepository */

        $pageRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Page\PageRepository::class);
        $pageRepository->init(false);

        /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\TypoScript\TemplateService $templateService */

        $templateService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\TypoScript\TemplateService::class);
        $typo3Branch = class_exists(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Information\Typo3Version::class)
            ? (new \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Information\Typo3Version())->getBranch()
            : TYPO3_branch;

        if (version_compare($typo3Branch, '9.0', '<')) {
            $templateService->init();
        }

        $templateService->tt_track = false;

        $currentPage = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id;

        if ($currentPage === null) {
            // root page is not yet populated
            $localTSFE = clone $GLOBALS['TSFE'];

        if (version_compare($typo3Branch, '9.5', '>=')) {
                $localTSFE->fe_user = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FrontendUserAuthentication::class);
            }
            $localTSFE->determineId();
            $currentPage = $localTSFE->id;
        }

        if (version_compare($typo3Branch, '9.5', '>=')) {
            $rootLine = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(RootlineUtility::class, (int)$currentPage)->get();
        } else {
            $rootLine = $pageRepository->getRootLine((int)$currentPage);
        }
        $templateService->start($rootLine);

        $setup = $templateService->setup;
        return $setup;
    }
```

I have been stuck with it for days with no luck.
In 10.4 version I am getting an error message at clone $GLOBAL['TSFE'].

Error: "_clone on non-object"

I need to get currentpage information to successfully get typoscript setup from the template. Any other way to acheive this also welcome. I guess I am missing something in v10 changelog.

Comment: Are you doing this in the backend. Can you add some more context where your code snippet is called?

Comment: If it is in the backend, it is pretty straighforward: $GLOBALS['TSFE'] is not initialized in the BE, so $GLOBALS['TSFE'] does not contain an object, but please add that to the question. See also  https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/TSFE/Index.html#accessing-tsfe

Answer (score 4):

Use the context API instead of `$GLOBALS['TSFE']`:
see the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Context/Index.html)

As you do not state what data is important to you no further help possible.
Being more specific enables other to be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to access current page id but could not find any such field in context api documentaion.

Comment: I have seen your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66097519/get-current-pageid-in-typo3-v10-4) which is more specific, what could result in better answers. but I think you also need to give more information (more code **before** the first access to `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->id`) as Rudy asked for

Comment: Can you provide more details or a code snippets, see also Stack Overflow Help Center https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline."