# Get current pageid in TYPO3 v10.4

Tags: plugins, typo3, typo3-10.x

Previously in version 8 and 9, I could access the page id using the following

$currentPid = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id

I am now updating my plugin to support 10.4, the above snippet gives out a null value. How can I access the page id and then also the root of the page id. I need the root page to gather the typoscript info from the root template.

```
$currentPage = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id;

if ($currentPage === null) {
    $localTSFE = clone $GLOBALS['TSFE'];    
    if (version_compare($typo3Branch, '9.5', '>=')) {
        $localTSFE->fe_user = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FrontendUserAuthentication::class);
    }
    $localTSFE->determineId();
    $currentPage = $localTSFE->id;
}
$rootLine = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(RootlineUtility::class, $currentPage)->get();
    
$templateService->start($rootLine);

$setup = $templateService->setup;
return $setup;
```

After the first line the currentPage is being set to null.
Then an error is being thrown when cloning the $GLOBALS['TSFE'].
Error: _clone on non-object

Comment: `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->id` is still available in TYPO3 10.4. There have been some changes on when `$GLOBALS['TSFE']` is initiated though. Where exactly are you trying to access it?

Comment: I have added some additional code above and error statement. Hopefully now I have conveyed in properly.

Comment: This does not really look like a frontend plugin (where indeed you would have a ready-to-use $TSFE). This rather looks like an eID script or an early Middleware. Could you specify your context?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the initial comments `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->id` is still correct and the way to go in all current TYPO3 versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Current page:

```
$pageUid = (int)GeneralUtility::_GET('id');
```

Get root page:

```
protected function getRootPage($pageUid) {

        $page = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(RootlineUtility::class, $pageUid);
        $rootLines = $page->get();

        if(!empty($rootLines)) {
            foreach ($rootLines as $rootLine) {
                if(!empty($rootLine['is_siteroot']) && $rootLine['is_siteroot']) {
                    return $rootLine['uid'];
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Generally `GeneralUtility::_GET()` should be avoided since it is bound to be removed at some point.

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 Version 11.5, 2021.

Only this works for me:

```
$contentObj = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject();
$pageId = $contentObj->data['pid'];
```

Notice that this only works if the current `data` is a `tt_content` record. This is true if your code is executed in the context of a content plugin. But if not, then you cannot rely on this.

Source:
https://www.horst-muerdter.com/de/2017/08/24/typo3-8-page-id-in-controller-ermitteln/

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `$GLOBALS['TSFE']` was not initialized here. One of the reasons may be you are in a context where it is not initialized (e.g. backend context).

Another reason may be, that you are accessing it, before it was initialized. Have a look at the description of the request workflow in the breaking change [Breaking: #88540 - Changed Request Workflow for Frontend Requests](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.0/Breaking-88540-ChangedRequestWorkflowForFrontendRequests.html).

For newer TYPO3 versions, it is no longer recommended to access `$GLOBALS['TSFE']` directly. You can get the current page id like this:

In the Frontend context:

```
$pageArguments = $request->getAttribute('routing');
$pageId = $pageArguments->getPageId();
```

---

**Documentation**:

- [TSFE](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/TSFE/Index.html) in "TYPO3 Explained" (main developer resource)